# <form> con varios <form> dentro

Tags: php, javascript, html

tengo un problema en mi proyecto de residencia de la prepa, quiero almacenar los datos que se me requieren en la db y eh creado una parte de javascript para hacer una serie de operaciones que necesito,pero ese codigo lo tengo dentro del php. les comparto lo que tengo...

```html
<?php
    session_start();
    Include("librerias/conexion.php");
    $objBD=new ConexionSql('localhost','root','','liconsa');
    $objBD->Conectar();
 $bandera=false;
 $procedencia=$objBD->ConsultaSql("call RegresaProcedencia();");
  if ($_POST){

 if ($arr[0][6]==-1)
   {
        $bandera=true;
        echo "Este susario no existe";
   }
   else
   {
      $arr=$objBD->ConsultaSql("call BuscarAnalista('$nomina_ana','".sha1($pass_ana)."');");
        $_SESSION["id_ana"]=$arr[0][6];
        $_SESSION["nombre"]=$arr[0][0];
   if($_SESSION["id_ana"]==1)
   {
     header("location:admin.php");
   }
   else
   {
       header("location:analista.php");
   }
   }
 
 
   $fecha=$_POST["fecha"];
   $folio=$_POST["folio"];
   $horasol=$_POST["horasol"];
   $horamuestra=$_POST["horamuestra"];
   $horasalida=$_POST["horasalida"];
   $tipoleche=$_POST["tipoleche"];
   $temp=$_POST["temp"];
   $organo=$_POST["organo"];
   $origen=$_POST["origen"];
   $volumen=$_POST["volumen"];
   $prot1=$_POST["prot1"];
   $resultadoMK=$_POST["resultadoMK"];
   $prot2=$_POST["prot2"];
   $lec1=$_POST["lec1"];
   $tc1=$_POST["tc1"];
   $ftc1=$_POST["ftc1"];
   $fac1=$_POST["fac1"];
   $lec2=$_POST["lec2"];
   $tc2=$_POST["tc2"];
   $ftc2=$_POST["ftc2"];
   $fac2=$_POST["fac2"];
   $den1=$_POST["den1"];
   $resden=$_POST["resden"];
   $den2=$_POST["den2"];
   $fat1=$_POST["fat1"];
   $grasa1=$_POST["grasa1"];
   $promediograsa=$_POST["promediograsa"];
   $st=$_POST["st"];
   $sng=$_POST["sng"];
   $fat2=$_POST["fat2"];
   $grasa2=$_POST["grasa2"];
   $prom2=$_POST["prom2"];
   $st2=$_POST["st2"];
   $STM=$_POST["STM"];
   $caseina1=$_POST["caseina1"];
   $promediocas=$_POST["promediocas"];
   $STM2=$_POST["STM2"];
   $caseina2=$_POST["caseina2"];
   $gastado1=$_POST["gastado1"];
   $naoh1=$_POST["naoh1"];
   $resnaoh1=$_POST["resnaoh1"];
   $promedioacidez=$_POST["promedioacidez"];
   $fos=$_POST["fos"];
   $gastado2=$_POST["gastado2"];
   $naoh2=$_POST["naoh2"];
   $resnaoh2=$_POST["resnaoh2"];
   $h1=$_POST["h1"];
   $promediocrio=$_POST["promediocrio"];
   $h2=$_POST["h2"];
   $total1=$_POST["total1"];
   $total2=$_POST["total2"];

   $arr=$objBD->ConsultaSql("call InsertarAnalisis( ".$_SESSION["id_ana"].",'$fecha','$turno','$horasol',
                 '$horamuestra','$horasalida',
               '$tipoleche','$temp','$organo','$origen','$volumen',''$fat1','$fat2',
               $prot1','$prot2','$resultadoMK','$lec1','$lec2','$tc1','$tc2','$ftc1','$ftc2',
               '$fac1','$den1','$den2','$resden','$grasa1','$grasa2',
               '$promediograsa','$sng','$prom2','$st','$st2',
               ,'$STM','$STM2','$caseina1','$caseina2','$promediocas',
               '$gastado1','$gastado2','$naoh1','$naoh2','$resnaoh1','$resnaoh2','$promedioacidez',
               '$fos','$h1','$h2','$promediocrio',
               '$total1','$total2',@b);");
               /*( clv_analistaa,fecha_analisisa,turnoa,hrs_sola,hrs_muestra,
               hrs_liba,tipoa,tmperatura_lechea,organolepticoa, origena,volumena,
               fat1a,fat2a,pro1a,pro2a,promedio_prota,lectura1a,lectura2a,Temp_c1a,
               Temp_c2a,fct1a,fct2a,factor_LD1a,factor_LD2a, dencidad1a,dencidad2a,
               promedio_densa,grasa_gl1a,grasa_gl2a,promedio_grasaa,snga,st_milko1a,
               st_milko2a,st_gla,casein1a,casein2a,prom_casa,hsgastado1a,hsgastado2a,
               NNaoH1a,NNaoH2a,volmuestra1a,volmuestra2a,promacideza,fusfatasaa,
               crisco_h1a,crisco_h2a,crisco_proma,acidez_fin1a,acidez_fin2a,ida);*/



   
   
   

  }

 ?>

<script>
function Crioscopio() {
    try {
        var a = parseFloat(document.a.h1.value),
            b = parseFloat(document.a.h2.value);
        document.a.promedicrio.value = ((a + b) / 2);
    } catch (e) {

    }
}

function Caseina() {
    try {
        var a = parseFloat(document.b.caseina1.value),
            b = parseFloat(document.b.caseina2.value);
        document.b.promediocas.value = (a + b) / 2;
    } catch (e) {

    }
}

function MKSCAN() {
    try {
        var a = parseFloat(document.d.prot1.value),
            b = parseFloat(document.d.prot2.value);
        document.d.resultadoMK.value = ((a + b) / 2) * 10;
    } catch (e) {}
}

function Dencidad() {
    try {
        var t1 = parseFloat(document.e.tc1.value),
            t2 = parseFloat(document.e.tc2.value),
            lectura1 = parseFloat(document.e.lec1.value),
            lectura2 = parseFloat(document.e.lec2.value),
            factor1 = parseFloat(document.e.fac1.value),
            factor2 = parseFloat(document.e.fac2.value);
        if (t1 == 16) {
            x = document.e.ftc1.value = 0.0002;
        }
        if (t1 == 14) {
            x = document.e.ftc1.value = -0.0002;
        }
        if (t1 == 15) {
            x = document.e.ftc1.value = 0;
        }
        if (t2 == 16) {
            x1 = document.e.ftc2.value = 0.0002;
        }
        if (t2 == 14) {
            x1 = document.e.ftc2.value = -0.0002;
        }
        if (t2 == 15) {
            x1 = document.e.ftc2.value = 0;
        }
        if (t2 < 14) {
            x1 = alert("inserte el dato dentro del rango");
        }
        if (t2 > 16) {
            x1 = alert("inserte el dato dentro del rango");
        }
        if (t1 < 14) {
            x = alert("inserte el dato dentro del rango");
        }
        if (t1 > 16) {
            x = alert("inserte el dato dentro del rango");
        }

        x2 = document.e.den1.value = lectura1 + x + factor1;
        x3 = document.e.den2.value = lectura2 + x1 + factor2;
        document.e.resdenc.value = (x2 + x3) / 2;
    } catch (e) {

    }
}

function Grasa() {
    try {
        var a = parseFloat(document.c.fat1.value),
            f = parseFloat(document.c.st.value),
            b = parseFloat(document.c.fat2.value);
        c = document.c.grasa1.value = a * 10;
        d = document.c.grasa2.value = b * 10;
        g = document.c.promediograsa.value = (c + d) / 2;
        document.c.sng.value = g - f;
    } catch (e) {

    }
}

function Acidez() {
    try {
        var a = parseFloat(document.f.gastado1.value),
            b = parseFloat(document.f.gastado2.value),
            c = parseFloat(document.f.naoh1.value),
            d = parseFloat(document.f.naoh2.value);
        x1 = (((a * c) * 90) / 20);
        document.f.resnaoh1.value = x1.toFixed(2);
        x2 = ((b * c) * 90) / 20;
        document.f.resnaoh2.value = x2.toFixed(2);
        x3 = (x1 + x2) / 2;
        document.f.promedioacidez.value = x3.toFixed(2);
    } catch (e) {

    }
}
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title id="pagetitle">LICONSA</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/MisEstilos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="image/liconsafavicon.jpg" />

</head>

<body>
    <header>

        <div class="main-header">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="image/logo_liconsa.png" title="logo" height="100" width="200" />

                </div>
                <div class="social-links">
                    <ul>
                        <img src="image/logo_república.png" title="logo" height="100" width="200" />

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </header>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="analista.php">Inicio<span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="analisis.php">Analisis</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION["id_ana"]))
        {
         echo "<li><a href='analista.php'>Bienvenido: ".$_SESSION["nombre"]."</a></li>";
         if (! empty($_SESSION["nombre"]))
     {
      echo "<li><a href='cerrarsesion.php'>Cerrar sesión</a></li>";
     }

    }else{echo "<li><a href='iniciarsesion.php'>Iniciar Sesión</a></li>";
                 echo "<li><a href='registrar.php'>Registrarse</a></li>";}


  ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="container">
        <center>
            <h1>Analisis</h1>
        </center>
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="analisis.php" method="post">

            <table class='table table-hover'>
                <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th scope='col'>
                            <h4>Fecha</h4>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <h4>Turno</h4>
                        </th>

                    </tr>


                    <tr class='table-secondary'>
                        <td scope='row'><input type='date' name='fecha' size='5'></td>
                        <td>
                            <select name='turno' class='form-control'>
                                <option>Selecciona el turno</option>
                                <option>Dia </option>
                                <option>Tarde</option>
                                <option>Noche</option>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>

            <center>
                <h3>Para Leche En Pipas</h3>
            </center>
            <table class='table table-hover'>
                <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th scope='row'>
                            <h4>Hrs de solucion</h4>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <h4>Hrs. de muestra</h4>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <h4>Hrs. de salida</h4>
                        </th>
                    </tr>


                    <tr class='table-secondary'>
                        <td scope='row'><input type='time' name='horasol'></td>
                        <td><input type='time' name='horamuestra'></td>
                        <td><input type='time' name='horasalida'></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>

            <center>
                <h3>Datos De La Muestra De La Leche</h3>
            </center>
            <table class='table table-hover'>
                <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <td scope='col'>
                            <h4>Tipo De Leche</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Temperatura C⁰</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Organoleptico</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Origen</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Volumen</h4>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class='table-secondary'>
                        <td scope='col '>
                            <select name='tipoleche' class='form-control' size="0.5">
                                <option>selecciona el tipo de leche</option>
                                <option>Frisia </option>
                                <option>Mezcka</option>
                                <option>L.C</option>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type='number' name='temp'></td>
                        <td>
                            <select name='organo' class='form-control' size="0.5">
                                <option>selecciona el numero</option>
                                <option>1 </option>
                                <option>2</option>
                                <option>3</option>
                                <option>4</option>
                                <option>5</option>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name='origen' class='form-control' size="0.5">

                                <?php
      for($x=0;$x<count($procedencia);$x++)
      echo "<option value='".$procedencia[$x][0]."'>".$procedencia[$x][0]."</option>";
     ?>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type='number' name='volumen'></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>

            <center>
                <h3>Datos MK-Scan</h3>
            </center>
            <table class='table table-hover'>
                <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <td scope='col'>
                            <h4>PRO(lectura)</h4>
                        </td>
                        <td scope='col'>
                            <h4>Promedio(proteina (g/l))</h4>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <div>
                        <form name='d'>
                            <tr class='table-secondary'>
                                <td scope='row'>
                                    <input type='number' name='prot1' onchange='MKSCAN()'></td>
                                <td><input type='number' name='resultadoMK' readonly='readonly'></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class='table-secondary'>
                                <td scope='row'><input type='number' name='prot2' onchange='MKSCAN()'></td>
                                <td><input hidden></td>
                            </tr>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </thead>
            </table>
            <div>
                <form name="e">
                    <center>
                        <h3>Calculo De Dencidad Por Lactodencimetro</h3>
                    </center>
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>

                            <tr>
                                <td scope='col'>
                                    <h4>Lectura</h4>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h4>TC⁰</h4>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h4>FCT <>15c⁰</h4>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h4>Factor(LD)</h4>
                                </td>

                            </tr>


                            <tr class='table-secondary'>

                                <td scope='col'><input name='lec1' onchange='Dencidad()'></td>
                                <td><input name='tc1' onchange='Dencidad()'></td>
                                <td><input name='ftc1' readonly='readonly'></td>
                                <td><input name='fac1' value='0.0009' onchange='Dencidad()'></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class='table-secondary'>
                                <td scope='col'><input name='lec2' onchange='Dencidad()'></td>
                                <td><input name='tc2' onchange='Dencidad()'></td>
                                <td><input name='ftc2' readonly='readonly'></td>
                                <td><input name='fac2' value='0.0009' onchange='Dencidad()'></td>
                            </tr>


                        </thead>
                    </table>

                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>

                            <tr>

                                <td>
                                    <h4>Densidad (g/ml)</h4>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <h4>promedio</h4>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class='table-secondary'>
                                <td><input name='den1' readonly='readonly'></td>
                                <td><input name='resdenc' readonly='readonly'></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class='table-secondary'>
                                <td>
                                    <input name='den2' readonly='readonly'></td>
                                <td><input name='txtfecha' hidden></td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>


            <center>
                <h3>Datos Calculos</h3>
            </center>
            <table class='table table-hover'>
                <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th scope='col'>
                            <h4>Fat (lectura)*</h4>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <h4>Grasa</h4>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <h4>Promedio</h4>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <h4>ST(g/l)</h4>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <h4>SNG</h4>
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                    <div>
                        <form name='c'>
                            <tr class='table-secondary'>
                                <td scope='row'>
                                    <input type='number' name='fat1' onchange='Grasa()'></td>
                                <td><input type='number' name='grasa1' readonly='readonly'></td>
                                <td><input type='number' name='promediograsa' readonly='readonly'></td>
                                <td><input type='number' name='st' onchange='Grasa()'></td>
                                <td><input type='number' name='sng' readonly='readonly'></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class='table-secondary'>
                                <td scope='row'>
                                    <input type='number' name='fat2' onchange='Grasa()'></td>
                                <td><input type='number' name='grasa2' readonly='readonly'></td>
                                <td><input type='number' name='prom2' hidden></td>
                                <td><input type='number' name='st2' hidden></td>
                                <td><input type='number' name='sng2' hidden></td>
                            </tr>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </thead>
            </table>

            <table class='table table-hover'>
                <thead>

                    <th scope='col'>
                        <h4>ST MILKO</h4>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <h4>Caseina</h4>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <h4>Promedio</h4>
                    </th>

                    <div>
                        <form name='b'>
                            <tr class='table-secondary'>
                                <td scope='row'><input type='number' name='STM'></td>
                                <td><input type='number' name='caseina1' onchange='Caseina()'></td>
                                <td><input type='number' name='promediocas' readonly='readonly'></td>


                            </tr>

                            <tr class='table-secondary'>
                                <td scope='row'><input type='number' name='STM2'></td>
                                <td><input type='number' name='caseina2' onchange='Caseina()'></td>
                                <td><input type='number' name='txtfecha' hidden></td>

                            </tr>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </thead>

            </table>

            <center>
                <h3>Acidez (g/l)</h3>
            </center>
            <table class='table table-hover'>
                <thead>


                    <th scope='col'>
                        <h4>NaOH gastado</h4>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <h4>NaOH</h4>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <h4>Volumen de la muestra(20ml)</h4>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <h4>Promedio</h4>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <h4>Fosfatasa</h4>
                    </th>
                    <div>
                        <form name='f'>
                            <tr class='table-secondary'>
                                <td scope='row'><input type='text' name='gastado1' onchange='Acidez()'></td>
                                <td><input type='text' value='0.1001' name='naoh1' onchange='Acidez()'></td>
                                <td><input type='number' name='resnaoh1' step='0.01' readonly='readonly'></td>
                                <td><input type='number' name='promedioacidez' step='0.01' readonly='readonly'></td>
                                <td><input type='text' name='fos'></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr class='table-secondary'>
                                <td scope='row'><input type='text' name='gastado2' onchange='Acidez()'></td>
                                <td><input type='text' value='0.1001' name='naoh2' onchange='Acidez()'></td>
                                <td><input type='number' name='resnaoh2' step='0.01' readonly='readonly'></td>
                                <td><input type='number' hidden></td>
                                <td><input type='text' hidden></td>

                            </tr>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </thead>

            </table>

            <center>
                <h3>Crioscopio</h3>
            </center>
            <table class='table table-hover'>
                <thead>


                    <th scope='col'>
                        <h4>H`</h4>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <h4>Promedio</h4>
                    </th>

                    <div>
                        <form name='a'>
                            <tr class='table-secondary'>
                                <td scope='row'><input value='-' name='h1' onchange='Crioscopio()'></td>
                                <td><input type='number' name='promedicrio' readonly='readonly'></td>


                            </tr>

                            <tr class='table-secondary'>
                                <td scope='row'><input value='-' name='h2' onchange='Crioscopio()'></td>
                                <td><input type='number' name='txtfecha' hidden></td>

                            </tr>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </thead>

            </table>

            <center>
                <h3>Acidez(ph final)</h3>
            </center>
            <table class='table table-hover'>
                <thead>


                    <td scope='col'>
                        <h4>Acidez 1</h4>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <h4>Acidez 2</h4>
                    </td>

                    <tr class='table-secondary'>
                        <td scope='row'><input type='number' name='total1'></td>
                        <td><input type='number' name='total2'></td>


                    </tr>


                </thead>

            </table>
            <center>
                <input type="submit" value="Registrar analisis" class="btn btn-success" onclick="Validar();">


                <li type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><a href="analista.php">
                        <font color="white">Cancelar
                    </a></li>
            </center>
            </br></br>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="wrap">

        </div>
        <div class="clear"> </div>
        <!---start-copy-right----->
        <div class="copy-tight">
            <p> Realizado por:<a>
                    <h4>Roberto Avalos Olloqui
                </a></p>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>


    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

lo que hago con el script es realizar una serie de operaciones matemáticas para sacar el promedio de x resultados, los intercambio con el html por medio de un form, el problema es que tengo muchos form y no se si esto pueda ser posible o si es valido?
en la parte de conteiner de html capturo los datos que necesito para realizar las operaciones, todo marcha bien, el problema es que no me los datos no me los captura en la base de datos, como comento no se si es porque tengo varios form anidados dentro de un form, o como es que le puedo hacer para poder realizar la inserción de los datos a la base de datos.... por favor necesito de su ayuda, muchas gracias por su atención 
pd: soy nuevo en esta gran comunidad :)

Comment: Puedes agregar el html?

Comment: Si utilizas PHP con los `<form>` anidados causará problemas, puedes utilizar un solo form que contenga todos tus inputs y podrás enviar los valores sin problemas.

Comment: Concuerdo con vick.

Comment: esta agregado Bicho... Vick lo que pasa es que estoy utilizando varios <form> para el intercambio y operaciones de los inputs. si viste el código, tengo un <script> donde hago los cálculos pongo los resultados